# How to get base url in cs cart view file

Tags: cs-cart

I am now analysis and working now  cs cart.I don't know how to get base url in cs cart(php and tpl file)??.please help me.my cs cart version 4.5.2.

```
many time my self searched google.But i don't have the results.
```

Answer (score 1):

base url in php:

```
fn_url('');
```

base url in tpl:

```
{''|fn_url}
```

Answer (score 0):

base URL is actual your domain: `http://example.com/` without the controller.
If you want to get both current URL and controller of the page you are working on, you should use this:

```
{$config.current_url|fn_url}
```